# How do I know if a filament is abrasive?

Tags: filament-choice, knowledgebase, filled-pla

There are tons of fancy filaments around. And a lot are super nice to look at or have super cool properties, like carbon-filled nylon being comparatively far stronger than other material, wood fill is aesthetically pleasing and even just Glow in the dark! But a maker space nearby just banned any of those as *abrasive* filament. But, how can I know if my filament is abrasive?

Comment: Usually, the filament is advertised as being abrasive. Or, the advertisement/filament properties say to use a (hardened) steel nozzle.

Comment: glow in the dark is extremely abrasive, wood notsomuch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A filament made of pure plastic won't be abrasive. The abrasion comes from the added particles.

Filaments with added particles of any kind (there are not so many after all: glass/carbon fibres, metals, glow in the dark, wood, stone) will usually be always be advertised as such because they always carry a higher price tag compared to the plain plastic, therefore you know that it contains potentially abrasive particles.

Once you know that particles are added, most of the time they will be abrasive: as far as I know, only cork is not, any other kind of particles I listed (including wood particles) may easily scratch brass.

If it were your printer, we could discuss how much each kind of particles will abrade, but in your case the ban seems to be complete, therefore only plain plastics (including "plus/+/Pro" blends, like for PLA and ABS) are allowed.

Comment: I was going to write a similar heuristic answer like this before you did it first, but I was unsure if it's complete. I seem to recall at least some nylon variants being warned about as abrasive and don't understand the mechanism there.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE nylon 6, 66, 12 are not abrasive by themselves. Those variants you mention maybe comprise fillers?

Comment: Glow in the Dark isn't always advertized as containing particles

Comment: Do note that diamond particles filled filament exists that is not abrasive! (According to their claim and reported tests)